# How do I raise a number by another number (num1^num2)

Tags: c, pow

This is my code. I get `3^2=1`. I have included the math library.

```
case '^':
    printf("The result is %d\n",(num1^num2));
    break;
```

Comment: `^` does not do what you think it does, in C++. It's a bitwise exclusive-or operator. There is no power operator in C or C++, for integers. You just have to do it the old fashioned way: multiplication. P.S. `std::pow()` does not do what you think it might do either, when integers are involved.

Comment: In my case I wouldn't know what the user will enter I know num1*num2 would not work in my situation. hmm would you happen to have any direction on what I should do?

Comment: Like I said: the old-fashioned way. That is: if you want to raise 3 to the 5th power, multiply 3 by itself five times.

Comment: You do NOT want to do it by multiplying. Use the pow() function.  That's in the math.h library in C, or the math library in C++

Comment: You do NOT want to do it by `pow()` function in the math.h library.  Use multiplication for `int`.

Comment: @Eljay: `pow` is fine, since `double` can represent every `int` exactly. If you care about performance, it’s “use multiplication in exponentiation by squaring”.

Comment: `pow()` is not fine, because `pow()` uses double and internally a log table, which can have some variation causing the double to int conversion to be off from what it would be compared to using a for loop and `int` multiplication.

Comment: I'm new to C can someone give me an example on how I may be able to accomplish this? I am using my lecture notes and will attend office hours but in the mean time I'm confused lol.

Comment: @AyshaAbdalla: The duplicate links in the banner at the top of your question have answers that include code.

Comment: @Eljay And if the exponential is a large number?  If it's 2 or 3, sure use multiplication.  If its a variable, you use pow not a multiplication loop.  If you use multiplication for a non fixed exponential you're going to get a nice talking to from your seniors.  If you're actually using big enough numbers for the double to be an issue, you should be using a more sophisticated math library and a BigInt type class.

Comment: @GabeSechan • that does not appear to be the case in the OP's code.

Comment: @Eljay Looking at his question where he raises num1^num2 it certainly is.  And given he's writing a calculator, which commonly has a "^" button and is obviously not experienced enough to understand the perf issues of multiplication, telling him to do it that way is negligence.  In fact look at his code-  he's very obviously implementing a generic ^ button which would NOT be just a 2 or 3